# ionic Async-await not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

my code is:

```
async getDetails(){
  for(var i=0;i<this.results.length;i++){
      // this.booking.length=0;
      // this.hbl.length=0;
      var hblList=[];
      var bookingList=[];
      await this.api.get("track/dtl", 
      {
       loadPortId: this.results[i].loadPortId,
        dischargeId:this.results[i].dischargeId,
        scheduleId: this.results[i].scheduleId
      })
      .subscribe(res1 => {
        //let resp1 = res1;
        this.details= res1;
        bookingList.length=0;
        hblList.length=0;
        for(var j=0;j<this.details.length;j++){
          if(this.details[j].bookNo!== undefined){ 
            bookingList.push(this.details[j]);
           }else if(this.details[j].hblNo!== undefined){
            hblList.push(this.details[j]);
           }
         }
        //  this.results[i]["hbl"]=this.hbl;
        //   this.results[i]["booking"]=this.booking;
         console.log("this.hbl inside subscribe::::::::::::"+hblList);
        console.log("this.booking  inside subscribe::::::::::::"+bookingList);
        console.log("this.results[i]  after::::::::::::"+this.results[i]);
        });

        this.results[i]["hbl"]=hblList;
        this.results[i]["booking"]=bookingList;
        console.log("this.hbl after::::::::::::"+hblList);
        console.log("this.booking  after::::::::::::"+bookingList);
        console.log("this.results[i]  after::::::::::::"+this.results[i]);
        this.getCurrent(this.results[i].queries[0]);

    }

  }
```

I want to make async call for each for loop item. could anyone please help me to use async-await to make sure the first and every async call is completed prior to the next call.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no means of trying your code or trying mine, but here, take a look at this one that should work in theory.

The main point is: you have to decide whether to use `Observable`s or to use Promises. Unfortunately the Angular team decided to return `Observable`s in their `http` module. Observables do not work with `async await`, but there is a simple conversion: [`Observable.prototype.toPromise()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html). Use that, and get rid of `.subscribe`.

```
async getDetails(){
    for(var i=0;i<this.results.length;i++){
        // this.booking.length=0;
        // this.hbl.length=0;
        var hblList=[];
        var bookingList=[];
        var res1 = await this.api.get("track/dtl", {
            loadPortId: this.results[i].loadPortId,
            dischargeId:this.results[i].dischargeId,
            scheduleId: this.results[i].scheduleId
        }).toPromise();

        this.details= res1;
        bookingList.length=0;
        hblList.length=0;
        for(var j=0;j<this.details.length;j++){
            if(this.details[j].bookNo!== undefined){ 
                bookingList.push(this.details[j]);
            } else if(this.details[j].hblNo!== undefined){
                hblList.push(this.details[j]);
            }
        }

        this.results[i]["hbl"] = hblList;
        this.results[i]["booking"] = bookingList;
        console.log("this.hbl after::::::::::::"+hblList);
        console.log("this.booking  after::::::::::::"+bookingList);
        console.log("this.results[i]  after::::::::::::"+this.results[i]);
        this.getCurrent(this.results[i].queries[0]);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you are subscribing in the Observable you're not using the async/await approach. Async/await works only with Promises, so, you need to transform your observable to promise first.

I don't know how your this.api works, but, maybe, you should have a toPromise() function. Using await you won't need to subscribe or to use ".then()" promise function.